# (BASIC) How do I solve this free falling question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, rocket-science, free-fall

If someone could just show me how to solve part A, I think I can try the rest on my own. Here is the question:

A model rocket is launched straight upward with an initial speed of 47.0 m/s. It accelerates with a constant upward acceleration of 2.50 m/s^2 until its engines stop at an altitude of 100 m.

a) What is the maximum height of the rocket?

b) How long after liftoff does the rocket reach maximum height?

c) How long is the rocket in the air?

I was able to get an answer for all questions, 193.97m, 4.324s, and 10.616s. However, apparently these are wrong.

Method: I first solved for the time it took for the rocket to reach 100m (2.019s). Then, I plugged that in to find the velocity of the rocket at 100m (52.0,58 m/s). Using that, I found the time it would take for the rocket (now with acceleration of gravity instead of 2.5m/s^2) to reach a point where velocity = 0. I got (2.305s). Then, I plugged that in to find the maximum point (193.97m).

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step of calculating the time to reach the 100 m and it's velocity at that point is absolutely correct but I think you have made a mistake while calculating the time it should take to reach the max. height.

Use this formula

$ t = \frac{(52.058)}{9.8}$

The time should be approx $5.31seconds$ and not $2.30sec$.

Hope it helps.